# How does sklearn compute nearest-neighbor affinity matrix for spectral clustering?

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Naively, if I specify number of nearest neighbors to be k, then for each node, it reaches out to find nearest k nodes and assign affinity to them as 1.

However, I observe that the affinity matrix generated by sklearn spectral clustering nearest-neighbor does not contains 0 and 1 only. Is it because there could be ties in the list of nearest neighbors? And so I assign 1/n to the n equally close neighboring nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the affinity matrix computed by sklearn spectral clustering with "nearest neighbor" option are 0, 1/2, and 1.

The values 0 and 1 are easy to understand, but how do the 1/2 entries arise?

Notice that the notion of k nearest neighbor is asymmetric with respect to two nodes, therefore, the affinity matrix A obtained using k-nearest-neighor is asymmetric. But the similarity matrix used in spectral clustering is symmetric, thus, spectral clustering takes the average of A and A.T.

The 1/2-values arise from asymmetric elements in A.